# Why is this a java program to display odd and even characters of a array not showing any output?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a java program to display odd and even characters of an array, it currently shows no output:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=scan.nextInt();// to get the num of words
    String[] inp=new String[10000];
    char[][] imArray=new char[10][];//2d array

    for(int j=0; j<n ; j++)//to get the strings
    {
      inp [j]= scan.nextLine();
      imArray[j] = inp[j].toCharArray();
    }

    for (int j=0; j<n ; j++)
    {
      for(int i=0;  i<inp[j].length() ;i=i+2)//even chars 
        System.out.println(imArray[i]);

      for (int k=0;  k<inp[j].length() ;k=k+2) //odd chars
        System.out.println("\t"+imArray[k]);

      System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

This doesn't throw errors but shows no output either. At least it doesn't show any run-time errors. It shows exception in thread main.

Comment: you need to improve question, add code formatting

Comment: yes!i m new here and yes, i have improved my question .take a look nw if u could.thanks.

Comment: So what is the exception?  Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: Re: *"have improved my question"*.  Not much.  I can see bad spelling, bad grammar, bad punctuation, etc.  More important though, the code indentation, whitespace, etc are a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me.
According to your comments on programme I think you should try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n=scan.nextInt();// to get the number of words
    String[] inp=new String[10000];


    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        inp [i]= scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Even Values");
    for(int j=0; j<=n ; j+=2){//even chars 

        System.out.print(inp[j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Odd Values");
    for(int k=1;  k<=n ;k=k+2){

        System.out.print(inp[k]+" ");
    }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, let's get the number of words we expect to get from the user. The maximum we allow is 10,000 words.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int wordsNumber = Math.min(Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()), 10000); // to get the num of words
String[] inp = new String[wordsNumber];
char[][] imArray=new char[wordsNumber][];//2d array
```

Now we get the words from the user and save them into the arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsNumber ; i++) { //to get the strings
  inp[i] = scan.nextLine();
  imArray[i] = inp[i].toCharArray();
}
```

Finally, iterate the arrays and for each words print its characters in the even places, then the characters in the odd ones. 
Print a newline after each word.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsNumber ; i++) {
  int wordLength = imArray[i].length;

  for(int j = 0;  j < wordLength; j+=2) { //even chars
    System.out.print(imArray[i][j]);
  }

  System.out.print("\t");

  for (int k = 1;  k < wordLength; k+=2) { //odd chars
    System.out.print(imArray[i][k]);
  }

  System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Actually, the use of the 2D array is not needed, I left to keep the resemblance with the code in the question.
It would be better to iterate **inp** array and use **String.charAt(int)**.

Comment: thanks a lot!!but could u explain why the Math.min function is required instead of simply using nextInt() alone

Comment: The code in your post had the initialization: String[] inp=new String[10000]; I assumed you wanted to give a limitation on the number of words. If not, than you can drop the Math.min call.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are creating an array of size `10`

```
char[][] imArray=new char[10][];//2d array
```

Then you are assigning it by

```
for(int j=0; j<n ; j++)//to get the strings
{
  inp [j]= scan.nextLine();
  imArray[j] = inp[j].toCharArray();
}
```

Here if the value of `n` is greater than `10,` it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
imArray[j] = inp[j].toCharArray(); // <--- Here ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Your program gets terminated as soon as the exception occurs, hence produces no output.

To solve this, declare your `imArray` of size `n` instead of `10`

```
char[][] imArray = new char[n][];
```